# Removing Padding of Subfigure

Tags: floats, subfloats, fbox

When dealing with subfigures, I always like to have things as much aligned as possible. For that I use a fbox to see where boundaries are and I constantly have issues with space I can't get rid of. Here is a small example.

```
\begin{figure*}
  \centering
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
  \fbox{
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \fbox{
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/4.experiments/images/lena.jpeg}
    }
  \caption{Picture 1}\label{fig:1}
  \end{subfigure}
  }
\end{figure*}
```

The output is the following

[image]

How can I fix this padding/margin in subfigures?

Comment: you are adding the space , compare `\fbox{a}` and `\fbox{ a }` you are using the latter, to get no padding at all, remove the space (end of line)

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unrelated to figures.

```
\fbox{
x
}
```

Produces the same output as `\fbox{ x }` with a space either side of x. You want `\fbox{x}` or equivalently

```
\fbox{%
x%
}
```